# Simple Threading, why does this happen? (C# WinForms)

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm currently exploring threading implementation in C# WinForms and I created this simple app:

I'm just wondering why the memory usage of this app keeps growing after I start, stop, start, and stop again the application. I'm having a thought that my thread instance doesn't really terminate or abort when I press the stop button. Please consider my code below, and any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadingTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private delegate void TickerDelegate(string s);
        bool stopThread = false;
        TickerDelegate tickerDelegate1;
        Thread thread1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tickerDelegate1 = new TickerDelegate(SetLeftTicker);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(disp));
            thread1.Start();
        }

        void disp()
        {
            while (stopThread == false)
            {
                listBox1.Invoke(tickerDelegate1, new object[] { DateTime.Now.ToString() });
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        private void SetLeftTicker(string s)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(s);
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopThread = true;
            if (thread1.IsAlive)
            {
                thread1.Abort();
            }
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopThread = false;
            thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(disp));
            thread1.Start();
        }

        private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (thread1.IsAlive)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Is Alive!");
            }
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, you should rename form1 and buttons 1-4 to have meaningful names; you're just lucky in this case that from reading the event code it's reasonably obvious which buttons correspond to which numbers.

Comment: Secondly, though I understand that this might just be to try out threads, the proper way to do this would be with a timer instead of a thread that sleeps for a second.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take that advice of yours.

Comment: I prefer doing a `.Join()` with a timeout set rather than an `.Abort()` on a thread. If the timeout expires then you can `.Abort()` as the last resort. If you need to interrupt it during a long `.Sleep()` then you can do an `.Interrupt()` but make sure you catch the `ThreadInterrupted` exception.

Comment: @hydrogen: does this one will solve my problem?

Comment: Not really but I think it's good practice. .Abort() can lead to your thread leaving your data in a rancid state.

Comment: How much memory does it leak? If it's 1MB, that would mean that the thread's stack isn't going away.

Comment: @Gabe: Initially it consumes 8,652 K. then when I stop it and start again it became 9,304 K, then 9,544 K, so on.. not consistent, but for sure it always increases its mem. usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, there are several recommendations:

### Use a Volatile Flag

Make your flag volatile... if you don't, then an update to the flag *may never* be seen by the thread.

```
volatile bool stopThread = false;
```

### Set to Background

Set the `IsBackground` property to true: it forces the thread to be terminated if the application exits, otherwise you may get a "ghost thread" which exists even after the application has closed.

```
thread1.IsBackground = true;
thread1.Start();
```

If the thread just started sleeping, then you will abort it even before it has had a chance to read the flag... furthermore you don't want to use `Abort` because:

> ...if one thread calls Abort on another
>   thread, the abort interrupts whatever
>   code is running. There is a chance the
>   thread could abort while a finally
>   block is running, in which case the
>   finally  block is aborted. There is
>   also a chance that a static
>   constructor could be aborted. In rare
>   cases, this might prevent instances of
>   that class from being created in that
>   application domain.

### Use Interrupt instead of Abort

So instead of using abort, I would recommend that you call `Interrupt` and you handle the exception inside the thread:

```
private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // have another method for re-use
    StopThread();
}

private void StopThread()
{
    stopThread = true;

    // the time out is 100 ms longer than the thread sleep
    thread1.Join(1100);

    // if the thread is still alive, then interrupt it
    if(thread1.IsAlive)
    {
        thread1.Interrupt();
    }
}
```

### Don't "Leak" Threads

You're leaking threads every time you click the Start button... if `thread1` is already assigned a thread and you assign *another* thread to it, then the previous one will continue to exist. You need to stop the previous thread before you start another one.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // stop the previous thread
    StopThread();

    // create a new thread
    stopThread = false;
    thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(disp));
    thread1.IsBackground = true;// set it to background again
    thread1.Start();
}
```

### Handle the Interrupt

Finally, you need to handle the interrupts in your thread:

```
void disp()
{
    try
    {
        while (stopThread == false)
        {
            listBox1.Invoke(tickerDelegate1, new object[] { DateTime.Now.ToString() });
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    catch(ThreadInterruptedException)
    {
        // ignore the exception since the thread should terminate
    }
}
```

I think that's about it... oh... actually, there is one more thing: **Thread Carefully!** ;)

Comment: The OP's code will leak threads if you keep pushing start but he says he's doing start, stop, start, stop, etc. So that wouldn't explain the growing memory. I think it's just normal GC behavior as the memory is reclaimed when he uses GC.Collect. But good advice nonetheless.

Comment: @Josh, I don't know why the memory is growing, your guess about the GC behavior is probably correct... the start button issue was indeed intended to be a comment on another area where threads may leak. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

New threads are pretty expensive in terms of memory. The default stack size is 1MB I believe for each new thread. Others have mentioned that calling Abort on a thread isn't really a good way to end a thread (and if the thread is blocking, it may not even abort the thread.) However, in your case I don't think Abort is the reason you are seeing memory grow.

Basically, the .NET garbage collector probably just has not gotten around to freeing up the memory it has allocated. You could try forcing a collection using GC.Collect() but you shouldn't do this in production code.

Comment: I tried GC.Collect() and it seems fine. The memory usage of the application seems to not grow anymore. But as you have said, this is some kind of workaround to the problem, not really the answer.

Comment: The answer is that there is no problem. .NET's garbage collector is triggered by memory needs. In other words, it is perfectly normal (and acceptable) to see unused memory hang around in a process. When the memory is needed, it will be released.

Answer (score 0):

In btnStop_Click, you set the flag to true, but then immediately check to see if it's still alive. This doesn't give the thread a chance to terminate naturally. Instead, you should perform a wait on the thread using Join (as hydrogen suggests), and if it times out (for whatever reason) then abort the thread.

Comment: hmm... If you don't mind sir, can you please site an example?